# How to get a double value from an object posted with NSNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having issues extracting a double from an NSObject.
I am receiving a notification like so

```
NSString *key = @"Post";
NSDictionary *dictionary = [notification userInfo];
Post* post = [dictionary objectForKey:key];

CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
zoomLocation.latitude = post.lat;
zoomLocation.longitude = post.lng;

NSLog(@"%f", post.lat);
NSLog(@"%@", post);
```

The NSLog for post.lat is nan. The NSLog for post is

(entity: Post; id: 0x85e9820  ; data: {
    created = "2013-10-08 16:25:36 +0000";
    lat = "-33.886336";
    lng = "151.209565";
    "post_id" = 2418;
})

Hopefully it is something really simple I am missing. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: When I try to use [post.lat doubleValue] it gets an error that prevents building "Bad receiver type 'double'"

ANSWER: I needed to extract the value like this

```
[[post valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
```

Comment: ok then so now its clear that Post.double is indeed a double since you get that error. This looks to me like the variable in the Post output is somehow different from the property variable. you would need to post the interface and such for the Post class.

Comment: Ok I updated my answer with the new information you provided.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using "%lf" to log a double? That should give you a warning in modern Xcode.

Comment: What result does an `NSLog(@"Class: %@", NSStringFromClass([[post lat] class]))` give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see double quotes around the values of lat and png. That likely means that those values are really strings and not numbers.

If that is the case then you can use `NSString#doubleValue` to get a converted numeric value that is compatible with `CLLocationCoordinate2D.latitude/longitude`.

Comment: you are on to something, but it cant be that simple since he already tried sending a doubleValue message and it tells him the receiver type is a double. See my updated answer for what I think is happening.

Comment: Hey guys thank you for taking the time to look at the question. It turns out I had to do

    [[post valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];

Your answer gave me the clue I needed. Stupid thing is I did this in a  previous part of my code but forgot to this time.

Answer (score 0):

depends on what class "lat" is. if it is an NSNumber then do `[post.lat doubleValue]`

**Edit:** from your updated question we see now that the Post.lat is indeed a double. However, as @St3fan pointed out the double quotes in the entity output make it appear as though that value is a string. So you have a double that is inited to NaN and is used for the property and another lat variable that is a string it would seem. Two separate variables.

Comment: In the Post object it is a double

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try it like this:

```
NSDictionary *location = @{@lat,@lng};
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NOTIFICATION" object:location];
```

Then get the location like this:

```
NSDictionary *location = notification.object;
```